# django on google app engine with relational database

Tags: django, google-app-engine

So is there any other way to use mysql database with django app on app engine? I found nice solution but it is not free - Google SQL Cloud seem to work great. But how about, moving django app to appengine and connecting to other hosting with mysql db? Or do you have any other solutions?

So to sum up - is there any way to work GAE with outside database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have found the answer:

The Python Development Server in the Google App Engine SDK can use a locally-installed MySQL server instance to closely mirror the Google Cloud SQL environment during development.
More info here-> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide

Comment: This is only for development and testing.  It's designed to mimic App Engine behavior, but it's not designed to be used as a production server.